# How does Ruby manage localhost communications via TCP under Windows 7?

Tags: ruby, windows, c++11, tcp, unreal-engine4

I am trying to implement a simple local TCP communication between a Ruby server and a C++ library interfaced to Unreal Engine 4.

I have used some sample code for the ruby server, which uses the `socket` library and instanciates a `TCPServer`:

```
require 'socket'

puts "Starting up server..."
# establish the server
## Server established to listen for connections on port 2008
server = TCPServer.new(15300)
# setup to listen and accept connections
while (session = server.accept)
 #start new thread conversation
 ## Here we will establish a new thread for a connection client
 Thread.start do
   ## I want to be sure to output something on the server side
   ## to show that there has been a connection
   puts "log: Connection from #{session.peeraddr[2]} at
          #{session.peeraddr[3]}"
   puts "log: got input from client"
   ## lets see what the client has to say by grabbing the input
   ## then display it. Please note that the session.gets will look
   ## for an end of line character "\n" before moving forward.
   input = session.gets
   puts input
   ## Lets respond with a nice warm welcome message
   session.puts "Server: Welcome #{session.peeraddr[2]}\n"
   # reply with goodbye
   ## now lets end the session since all we wanted to do is
   ## acknowledge the client
   puts "log: sending goodbye"
   session.puts "Server: Goodbye\n"
 end  #end thread conversation
end   #end loop
```

This application, if tested with a ruby client, works perfectly fine.

This is the client:

```
require 'socket'
# establish connection
## We need to tell the client where to connect
## Conveniently it is on localhost at port 15300!
clientSession = TCPSocket.new( "localhost", 15300 )
puts "log: starting connection"
#send a quick message
## Note that this has a carriage return. Remember our server
## uses the method gets() to get input back from the server.
puts "log: saying hello"
clientSession.puts "Client: Hello Server World!\n"
#wait for messages from the server
## You've sent your message, now we need to make sure
## the session isn't closed, spit out any messages the server
## has to say, and check to see if any of those messages
## contain 'Goodbye'. If they do we can close the connection
 while !(clientSession.closed?) &&
          (serverMessage = clientSession.gets)
  ## lets output our server messages
  puts serverMessage
  #if one of the messages contains 'Goodbye' we'll disconnect
  ## we disconnect by 'closing' the session.
  if serverMessage.include?("Goodbye")
   puts "log: closing connection"
   clientSession.close
  end
 end #end loop
```

Server output:

```
Starting up server...
log: Connection from ::1 at
          ::1
log: got input from client
Client: Hello Server World!
log: sending goodbye
```

But when I try to connect to the server using C++11 and the TCP functions in Unreal Engine 4 I do not get any kind of response from the server implemented in ruby (not even "Connection from...").

To understand what was the problem I tried to run some netwrok analysis, starting from the simplest (Window's Resource Monitor), to the most complex (ZenMap). In no case there was a single service running with the selected port open (port 15300). I have double checked every single possible cause for this (e.g. firewall, other security software) but there was no block to the ruby interpreter.

In order to understand why such a simple application is not working I started using Wireshark. It was then that I noticed that there is no local loopback interface, which required me to use RawCap (wich manages to capture the local communications and dump them on file). Using it I managed to dump the local communications on my machine during both a run of the ruby client/server pair and Cygwin Socat/Unreal Engine 4. What I found was pretty baffling: there were NO open local TCP sockets on the port for the ruby pair (port 15300), but the TCP ports opened by Unreal Engine 4 were there (along with port 15301, the one I used for the tests).

**Update 01**

I have changed the code in my Unreal Engine 4 application, as the first version used an included TCPsocket builder which used `bind` by default instead of `connect`. Now the code is:

```
bool UNetworkBlueprintLibrary::NetworkSetup(int32 ServerPort) {

    bool res = false;

    // Creating a Socket pointer, wich will temporary contain our 
    FSocket* Socket = nullptr;
    ISocketSubsystem* SocketSubsystem = ISocketSubsystem::Get(PLATFORM_SOCKETSUBSYSTEM);

    // Instead of that useless FTcpSocketBuilder I will try to create the socket by hand and then debug it... >:(
    if (SocketSubsystem != nullptr) {
        // Try to create a stream socket using the system-intependent interface
        Socket = SocketSubsystem->CreateSocket(NAME_Stream, TEXT("Server Socket"), false);

        if (Socket != nullptr) {
            FIPv4Address ServerAddress = FIPv4Address(127, 0, 0, 1);
            TSharedRef<FInternetAddr> LocalAddress = ISocketSubsystem::Get(PLATFORM_SOCKETSUBSYSTEM)->CreateInternetAddr();
            uint16 castServerPort = (uint16)ServerPort;

            // Attach received port and IPAddress to Internet Address pointer
            LocalAddress->SetIp(ServerAddress.GetValue());
            LocalAddress->SetPort(castServerPort);

            bool SocketCreationError = !Socket->Connect(*LocalAddress);

            if (SocketCreationError)
            {
                GLog->Logf(TEXT("Failed to create Server Socket as configured!"));

                SocketSubsystem->DestroySocket(Socket);

                Socket = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }



    if (Socket != nullptr){
        UNetworkBlueprintLibrary::ServerSocket = Socket;
        res = true;
    }
    else {
        res = false;
    }

    return res;
}
```

In order to test whether the code in Unreal Engine 4 is working or not I have used `socat` under Cygwin:

```
socat tcp-listen:15300 readline
```

Once my Unreal Engine 4 application starts I can send data over the socket. I have confirmed this works, removing the possibility that my application developed in Unreal Engine 4 was not communicating through the TCP socket.

Given this positive result I have tried again to use the server code reported on top of this question, removing the lines that wait for a message from the client but the result is the same: the server does not even output the debug lines it should print when there is a connection:

```
puts "log: Connection from #{session.peeraddr[2]} at #{session.peeraddr[3]}"
```

**Update 02**

Back once again!

I have managed to make `ruby` and `Unreal Engine 4` communicate through local TCP sockets. What I needed to make the ruby server work was explicitly providing the local address, like so:

```
server = TCPServer.new("127.0.0.1", 15300)
```

However, even if this matter is solved, I am still interested in some of the questions I put the first time.

**Update 03**

Just one consideration that I made in the last hour.

When I did not provide an explicit server address the server, this command

```
   puts "log: Connection from #{session.peeraddr[2]} at
          #{session.peeraddr[3]}"
```

Returned

```
log: Connection from ::1 at
          ::1
```

Which is indeed correct! `::1` is the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1`, so it looks like that `ruby` assumes that it has to create an IPv6 socket, instead of an IPv4. `Unreal Engine 4` does not provide an IPv6 interface, so this might have been the reason why the application did not work.

Now communications over `localhost` when dumped, show the following communications over port 15300:

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    105 7.573433    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      52     9994→15300 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
    106 7.573433    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      52     15300→9994 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
    107 7.573433    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      40     9994→15300 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0
    108 7.583434    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     15300→9994 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=26
    109 7.583434    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      40     9994→15300 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=27 Win=7936 Len=0
    110 7.583434    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     15300→9994 [PSH, ACK] Seq=27 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=16
    111 7.583434    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      40     9994→15300 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=43 Win=7936 Len=0
    208 16.450941   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      52     9995→15300 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
    209 16.451941   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      52     15300→9995 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
    210 16.451941   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      40     9995→15300 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0
    211 16.456941   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     15300→9995 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=26
    212 16.456941   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      40     9995→15300 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=27 Win=7936 Len=0
    213 16.456941   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     15300→9995 [PSH, ACK] Seq=27 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=16
    214 16.456941   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      40     9995→15300 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=43 Win=7936 Len=0
```

When a packages show a `LEN` of either 26 or 16 means that they are sending either

```
Server: Welcome 127.0.0.1.
```

or

```
Server: Goodbye.
```

I just wanted to share this information, as it is not really useful for the answer, but shows how IPv6 communications do not pass through the standard `localhost` virtual adapter.

**The questions**

What I would like to understand is:

- As there is no local loopback interface how does ruby communicate through local TCP sockets?

Comment: How are you sure that unreal engine actually is listening to the port on localhost?

Comment: I'm initialising a TCP socket using the following code block:

`FTcpSocketBuilder SocketBuilder = FTcpSocketBuilder(TEXT("Server Socket"));` 
 `FIPv4Address ServerAddress = FIPv4Address(127, 0, 0, 1);`
 `FIPv4Endpoint ServerEndpoint = FIPv4Endpoint(ServerAddress, castServerPort);`

If I check on Window's Resource monitor and dump localhost communications using RawCap, once I run my Unreal Engine application I can see TCP communications opening on port 15300, which is passed to the function through BluePrint.

Comment: Sorry but everything became very long. Could you summarize what works, what does not work and what is exactly your question?

Comment: I have updated the question. **tl;dr:** `UE4` application communicates with `socat`, `socat` communicates with `ruby`, `ruby` does not communicate with `UE4` (i.e. with `C++`). `UE4` opens wanted port on local network, as does `socat`, `ruby` does not do it. Tested with `RawCap`. Why is it?